# C# Html Agility Pack ( SelectSingleNode )

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse this field, but can't get it to work. Current attempt:

```
var name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='my_name']").InnerHtml;


<h1 class="bla" id="my_name">namehere</h1>
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Appreciate any help.

@John - I can assure that the HTML is correctly loaded. I am trying to read my facebook name for learning purposes. Here is a screenshot from the Firebug plugin. The version i am using is 1.4.0.

http://i54.tinypic.com/kn3wo.jpg

I guess the problem is that profile_name is a child node or something, that's why I'm not able to read it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What line does your code fail on? Your code as written works correctly.

Comment: I posted the line on which it fails.

Comment: Could you show the code that loads your HTML? Also, which object in your chain is null? Do you have multiple H1 tags with the same ID? What version of HTML Agility Pack are you using?

Answer (score 21):

The reason your code doesn't work is because there is JavaScript on the page that is actually writing out the `<h1 id='profile_name'>` tag, so if you're requesting the page from a User Agent (or via AJAX) that doesn't execute JavaScript then you won't find the element.

I was able to get my own name using the following selector:

```
string name = 
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@id='navAccountName']").InnerText;
```

Comment: This should be marked as an answer. This actually helped me. Dynamic generated code don't work in this dll.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//@id='my_name'").InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@id='my_name']").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async Task<List<string>> GetAllTagLinkContent(string content)
    {


        string html = string.Format("<html><head></head><body>{0}</body></html>", content);
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id='my_name']");
        return nodes.ToList().ConvertAll(r => r.InnerText).Select(j => j).ToList();

    }
```

It's ok with ("//a[@href]");  You can try it as above.Hope helpful