# VB2010 HtmlAgilityPack SelectSingleNode not returning a result

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Hey I'm trying to obtain some text from wikipedia using the following code. But it isn't returning any values for SelectSingleNode

```
        Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb

        doc = web.Load("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limnio")
        Dim Grape As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td")
        txtPOO.Text = Grape.InnerHtml.Trim
```

Maybe I imported the dll wrong? Any help would be appreciated! (I am a newbie)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3826452/1842065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you looked that XPath up via Chrome (or some other browser), but sadly it's no that easy, this is because Chrome shows you the HTML as it's being interpreted by Chrome.
You on the other hand have to look at the HTML as it's returned from the server.

When you look at the original HTML you'll notice that there is no tbody element, so your XPath was almost correct.

```
Dim Grape As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/table/tr[6]/td")
```

That should return the node you're looking for.

As for testing XPaths, the best tool i know of is the [Html Agility Pack Testbed](http://haptestbed.codeplex.com/) which let's you load an page and try different xpaths on it. You can also see the source of the page so it's all in one place. Plus, you'll see the HTML like it really is an not how chrome renders it.

Comment: Thank you!! it works! So in the future how would i look up the XPath of a certain node? I used Chrome to look up the previous XPath

Comment: @user3162084, well i've seen people use firebug for firefox to look up the xpath, but i'm not sure if that'll shield the same result as chrome does. I just look them up in firefox via `view source` and never had problems with that. however, you can't look them up like that but have to `build` them yourself. Another tool that might help is the HAP Testbed, i'll edit a link in my answer.